# How to refer to sibling/parent directory in `setup.cfg`

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
`- Root
  `- ProjectA
    `- setup.{cfg,py}
    `- PackageA
      `- __init__.py
  `- ProjectB
    `- setup.{cfg,py}
    `- PackageB
      `- __init__.py
```

which I am **not** allowed to change.

Also supposed that `Root` has **many** other unrelated folders, which make it not suitable to turn into a Python project folder.

`PackageB` wants to `import PackageA`. How can I declare this dependency in `Root/ProjectB/setup.cfg`, such that running `pip install .` in `Root/ProjectB/` will create a copy of `ProjectA/` in `Root/ProjectB/.venv/lib/.../site-packages`.

Seems somewhat reasonable?

Any attempt at using `..` in `package_dir` has failed me. Pip does not complain, but also does nothing.

So far the only working solution I have is to create a symbolic link `Root/ProjectB/PackageA -> ../ProjectA/PackageA`, and to put:

```
# in Root/ProjectB/setup.cfg
package_dir =
  PackageA = .
packages =
  PackageA
```

But in reality there's more than one `PackageA`, and symbolically linking to every package that `ProjectA` defines is tedious and ugly.

This seems like a reasonable ask: how do I make it so that `ProjectB` can import any package from `ProjectA` **without** altering the directory structure, and **without** turning `Root` into a Python project itself?